# VirtualBox bridged networking and remote desktop

Tags: networking, virtualbox, remote-desktop

I have a Windows 7 host running an Ubuntu 14.04 guest.  The guest has a bridged network connection.  When I connect to the host by remote desktop protocol (RDP), the guest loses network connectivity.  Once I login to the host console again, the guest regains network connectivity.  How can I avoid this, connecting by RDP to the host while maintaining connectivity to the guest?

Answer (score 0):

Use NAT/Host-Only networking to solve issues like this. What I believe is when you connect to the host machine over the RDP, it takes over the NIC and also the IP, hence your VM loses connectivity.
My suggestion though, use NAT and configure the port forwarding correctly, you'd be good to go. All the best.